# Disable noUnusedLocals and noUnusedParameters for specific files in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, tsconfig

I have a tsconfig file and I want to disable noUnusedLocals and noUnusedParameters for specific files only.
I have function in Migration file called **up**. I'm not using it anywhere in the code. Sequelize checks for it while migration. This function gives error when **noUnusedLocals is set to true**.
Is there a way to disable or ignore certain files for noUnusedLocals in tsconfig?